# Enable navigation of an interactive youtube video embedded on a website

Tags: youtube

The organization I work for has created an interactive YouTube video in which you can navigate around to other YouTube videos by clicking links within the video - sort of like a choose your own adventure type deal.

Anyway, I was working on a web page that references this video and I'd like to embed the video directly on the page.

The interactive portions actually work while the video is embedded, but unlike how it works when playing on YouTube, the url doesn't actually change and the back button is therefore non-functional.

So if I choose a path and determine that's not where I want to go, the only way to get back would be to reload the entire page and start from the beginning.

I'm guessing my best choice here is to just go ahead and link this off to YouTube, but I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing an obvious easy way to embed this video on the page and keep the back button functionality that's possible when the video plays on YouTube.

Thanks for your time!